# Store.load method in extjs time complexity

Tags: javascript, html, extjs, extjs4

I have the function in EXTJS which i get a store from a controller and then load it.

```
functionName: function (controller) {   
    return function() {

        Ext.widget('callWindow');
        var variable= cotroller.getCallWindowPopup();
        controller.getAccountsStore().load({
            params: {
                source_system_id: ssid
            },
            callback: function (records) {
                variable.loadRecord(records[0]);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

The account store is a json store which might have few thousand records.
Which of the operation is expensive here? getAccountsStore or the load method. If load is expensive how can i avoid calling it multiple times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getAccountsStore` is a lookup of a reference in a collection, its immediate. `load` of course is expensive. It loads all the data in the store, instantiating each record as a model object.

Normally, you don't need to call `load` more than once, unless your data changes, and you want to refresh.

You can reduce the loading time, if you use a paged store. This loads only one page of data into the store. This may or may not be acceptable in your context.

Comment: I have a situation where I have to call the load in two different functions with different parameters. How do I achieve that?

Comment: All depends on the data you load. If it is the same, and for instance the callback changes, you should not load more than once. But if the data is not the same, e.g. if the filter changes, you cannot get around loading on each change.

Comment: I added a global variable and stored the records[0] in it in the callback function, which I used it in other functions. Because, that is the object I wanted to access in other functions without calling the expensive load method.